# Maping data in React and want toggle specific button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I can't toggle a particular button. I want to toggle that particular button in an array of buttons. Here is [demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-glade-tv4iv?file=/src/App.js) link. Please correct it and share solved problem.

#### Code

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { data } from './data';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    toggle: true,
    index: ''
  })

  const onJoin = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      toggle: !state.toggle
    })
  }

  const onRequest = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      toggle: !state.toggle
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(data => {
        return(<div className='container'>
          <h1>{data.name}</h1>
          {state.toggle ?
          <button onClick={() => onJoin()}>Join</button>
          :
          <button onClick={() => onRequest()} >Request</button>
        }
        </div>)
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

You are using one state variable for all buttons. You need an array to keep track of which buttons are toggled

### Solution

Instead of making `toggle` a boolean, make it a boolean array.

### [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cache-mq56n?file=/src/App.js)

### Code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { data } from "./data";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    toggle: [],
    index: ""
  });

  const onJoin = (index) => {
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      toggle: state.toggle.filter((t) => t !== index)
    }));
  };

  const onRequest = (index) => {
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      toggle: [...state.toggle, index]
    }));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((d, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="container">
          <h1>{d.name}</h1>
          {state.toggle.includes(index) ? (
            <button onClick={() => onJoin(index)}>Join</button>
          ) : (
            <button onClick={() => onRequest(index)}>Request</button>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks..
So there is no need of index in state which is already declare?